# Views REST Endpoint With paragraph field

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 8, paragraphs

I've created a REST export view to get a paragraph field in a JSON format but I cannot get the result properly, so I used [Rest Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/rest_views) module but I got the results including something like these characters `\u003Ca href=\u0022\/colors\/gray-metallic\u0022 hreflang=\u0022en\u0022\u003EGray Metallic\u003C\/a\u003E`

Also, this paragraph field includes a term reference field.

So I want to render the data properly without these characters and as a plain text

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by using [jQuery.parseHTML()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) or you can use Javascript [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Something like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: drupalSettings.path.baseUrl + 'REST_VIEW_PATH/' + nid,
    success: function (data) {
        {
            var paragraphField = data[0]['FIELD_NAME'];
            $.each(paragraphField, function (index, item) {
                var fieldItem = $.parseHTML(item.FIELD_ID_IN_PARAGRAPH);
                console.log(fieldItem[0]['innerText']);
            });
        }
    }
});
```